# How does one alter the size and weight of type when using input text? Flash and AS2

Tags: flash, text, input

I have completed a simple contact form using Flash CS5 and AS2. Instead of having headings such as "your email", "subject" and "message" **outside** each text field, they are contained **inside** each relevant text field and are made up of input text. I would like to do two things:

1. To have the initial text (ie. "Subject") in a smaller size and heavier weight than the subsequent text typed in by the user.
2. I would also like the initial text (ie. "Subject") to disappear as soon as the user starts to type in the same box.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two text fields seems unpractical.  You can use the [onSetFocus handler](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary755.html) of the textfield and use `setTextFormat()` and/or `setNewTextFormat()` to change the font, and `text = "";` to erase the text.

```
tf.onSetFocus = function () { 
    tf.text=""; 
    tf.setTextFormat (format); 
    tf.setNewTextFormat (format); 
}
```

where tf is the text field and format is a valid TextFormat object.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I overread that. I have changed my answer to work in as2.

Comment: Thanks for that ... what would the complete AS look like?

Comment: Thanks very much for that ... presumably one can use the same code for other TextFields by changing **tf** to say **tf2**, **tf3** etc?

Comment: Of course you can :).  Was this the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the user to be able to interact with the field names "default" text? (e.g. to select it, to see the I-beam, etc)

If not, then why not just have an extra dynamic TextField behind the input TextFields, with your field names, and just set their `_visible` to `false` once the user has started to type.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer. That sounds rather cool! What would the AS be for that?

Comment: You can create the second TextField on the stage without any AS. Then you just need to hide it when the input one has text in it, react to one of its events, but unfortunately my AS2 is a bit rusty, haven't used it in years.

Comment: You can do it with just `tf.onChanged = function() { hint._visible = (tf.text.length < 1); }` where `hint` and `tf` are your two TextFields.

Comment: Thanks again ... so the "subject" would be the **hint** TextField and sit behind the **tf** TextField? Would I need to add any further AS?

Comment: Yes, and I don't think so (I did a quick test)